# Наречие «удивлённо» от глагола «удивить»? Что тогда образует глагол «удивлять»?

Tags: грамматика, словообразование, наречия

Удивлённо — наречие от прил. *удивлённый*;
удивлённый — от глагола *удивить* (сов. вид).

И как не перепутать само образование: то ли от *удивить* всё пошло, то ли от *удивлять*?

Answer (score 1):

> Что тогда образует глагол *удивлять*?

А должен?

> Почему наречие *удивлённо* образовано именно от глагола *удивить*?

Вопрос, конечно, не совсем корректно поставлен, но попробую ответить. 
Прежде всего, вопрос от какой именно формы из двух образовано наречие, несколько умозрителен. Любой выбор не будет грубой ошибкой. Но более естественно все-таки считать, что подобные "отглагольные" наречия образуются параллельно с отглагольными прилагательными и парными к ним причастиями совершенного вида, если не опосредовано через них. *Предать-преданный-преданно. умиротворить-умиротворенный-умиротворенно. округлить-округленный-округленно.*

С формами несовершенного вида такой очевидной параллели не получается, причастия несовершенного вида могут отсутствовать или иметь иные формы.

Что же касается словообразовательного суффикса -Л- то тут вообще нет единства в подходе. В наречиях (и прилагательных-причастиях) он может появляться независимым от глагола путем.

Так что выбор формы совершенного вида как первичной вполне оправдан.
Но я вполне допускаю, что в каком-то другом пособии это и подобные наречия возведут и к глаголам несовершенного вида, ориентируясь на внешнее сходство словообразовательных суффиксов.

Answer (score 0):

Удивить => Удивленный => Удивленно

Удивлять => Удивляемый => Удивляемо